# Encode (& decode) a URL as a string of letters

Tags: algorithm, string, encoding

I want a function that can encode any URL into a string of all letters (upper and lowercase), and another function to decode it back into a URL. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Sample API:

```
> 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'.url_to_chars
=> 'mgzGBORuRcFSfNXDpDbVgzzvANHLqIEcgjCAXsKbNXGouOckToKkZRBnvE'


> 'mgzGBORuRcFSfNXDpDbVgzzvANHLqIEcgjCAXsKbNXGouOckToKkZRBnvE'.chars_to_url
=>'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) is a simple way to do this:

```
String encoded = Base64.encode("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask".getBytes());
System.out.println(encoded);
System.out.println(new String(Base64.decode(encoded)));
```

Prints:

```
aHR0cDovL3N0YWNrb3ZlcmZsb3cuY29tL3F1ZXN0aW9ucy9hc2s=
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

**Update:**

If you actually look at the [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) URLs are case-insensitve and only a range of characters are allowed. There's plenty of space to map it as long as your input strings are valid encoded URLs.

```
import string
l = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
t = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + ";/?:@=&$-_.+!*'(),"

d = dict(zip(l,t))
e = dict(zip(t,l))
```

d and e are the decoding and the reverse encoding mapping.

```
[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd'), ('e', 'e'), ('f', 'f'), ('g', 'g'), ('h', 'h'), ('i', 'i'), ('j', 'j'), ('k', 'k'), ('l', 'l'), ('m', 'm'), ('n', 'n'), ('o', 'o'), ('p', 'p'), ('q', 'q'), ('r', 'r'), ('s', 's'), ('t', 't'), ('u', 'u'), ('v', 'v'), ('w', 'w'), ('x', 'x'), ('y', 'y'), ('z', 'z'), ('0', 'A'), ('1', 'B'), ('2', 'C'), ('3', 'D'), ('4', 'E'), ('5', 'F'), ('6', 'G'), ('7', 'H'), ('8', 'I'), ('9', 'J'), (';', 'K'), ('/', 'L'), ('?', 'M'), (':', 'N'), ('@', 'O'), ('=', 'P'), ('&', 'Q'), ('$', 'R'), ('-', 'S'), ('_', 'T'), ('.', 'U'), ('+', 'V'), ('!', 'W'), ('*', 'X'), ("'", 'Y'), ('(', 'Z'), (')', '0'), (',', '1')]
```

Decode and encode are only simple mappings:

```
def encode(s): return ''.join(e[c] for c in s)
def decode(s): return ''.join(d[c] for c in s)
```

The output is:

```
enc = encode("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
>>> decode(enc)
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'
>>> enc
'httpNLLstackoverflowUcomLquestionsLask'
```

Comment: There's still Base32 and hex. It's not too hard to find an appropriate mapping from byte -> [A-z][0-9].

Comment: I can't use numbers either; it has to be only letters (anyone know of a base52 encoding function written in ruby?)

Comment: Also, my URLs are case-sensitive (weird that the RFC says otherwise; I've found that they're case-sensitive in 99% of real-world cases)

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of base64 encoding and decoding.

Depending on the data you can use some encryption and decryption algorithm to accomplish this. It will put the string into text with no special characters etc. With the added bonus that the data is encrypted.

Comment: Encryption and Decryption are by design computationally expensive. A simple mapping would do.

Comment: Well this comes down to what the user is trying to do. The question was quite open.